# Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition Offline Installer

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I have downloaded all the VS packages ( around 35 GB) using the below command line.
`vs_community.exe --layout c:\vslayout --lang en-US`

Now, I use the command `vs_community.exe --noweb` to install in a PC with no internet connection. As the installer option is offline mode, but still the installer says not connected to internet.

Comment: Have you manually install the certificate? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-certificates-for-visual-studio-offline?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Martheen I did not do this before. I will do and update here.

Comment: @Martheen Great... it worked for me. If you post as answer, I can accept it because it worked for me. ( Note: Something went wrong in between and I could not open VS, so I have removed all components and reinstalled. But the issue is not related with any thing from your answer)

Comment: @Rauf, I have added for you  and also thanks to Martheen for sharing the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To help improve the issue, I add an answer here. Also, thanks to **Martheen** for sharing the info.

**Answer**

You have to install certificates from the offline package to install the VS because the new environment is offline and cannot get the requests and permissions for installing VS.

So you have to open the **certificates** folder of the offline package to install them one by one to get that.

You can [refer to this for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-certificates-for-visual-studio-offline?view=vs-2019).

**Update 1**

use a bat file to execute the offline installation of VS.

```
certmgr.exe -add [layout path]\certificates\manifestRootCertificate.cer -n "Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2011" -s -r LocalMachine root

.....

//add any for certs


vs_community.exe --noweb
```

Comment: I think it will be better if the installer can verify if the certs are installed (even if not actually installing them themselves due to the security implication on the article) and give the appropriate error message, just a dummy file signed with the latest cert should be enough to verify, or at the very least, mention the possibility in the error message.

Comment: It should be an suggestion for VS. And VS has provided some suggestions under the link.  As you seen from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-certificates-for-visual-studio-offline?view=vs-2019#why-are-the-certificates-from-the-certificates-folder-not-installed-automatically), Microsoft does not support it and the team has its own reason why it's not supported. So we cannot do anything here to make it automatically. We could only create a bat file to execute them in combination.

Comment: No, I'm not asking about automating it, I've mentioned that I understand Microsoft isn't going to do that. Just additional message like "no internet connection, you might need to install the certificate at the directory xx" would be better than the current state

Comment: That prompt is what we should do, and it might be too complex. It is better to integrate the installation certificate operation into the offline installation by default. My idea is that we should make the installation of the certs a part of the offline vs installation so that we will never consider that. Check my updated answer.